# Re-arrangement within a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like as follows:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.
  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.
  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.
  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.
  5.  5.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.
  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  3.  3.  3.  3.
  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.
  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.
  4.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.
  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.
  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.
  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
  2.  2.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.
  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.
  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.
  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  6.  6.  6.  6.
  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.
  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.
  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.
  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.
  5.  5.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.
  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.]
```

Now I need to re-arrange the array without any spliting or slicing such that all of the 1s, 2s,---6s are grouped together. What would be the best way? The numbers change after every 22 elements. So the new array should have 88 entries of each number.

Part b of the question:

If I have an extended form of the above array with shape (528, 32768) and the values in the array are now completely random and I need to group values at the indices of 1s, 2s, 3s....... together with no sorting; what would be the best way?

Comment: Why no splitting and slicing?

Comment: What exactly are the prohibited operations? And if you care to elaborate, why so?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the fastest solution:

```
array( sorted( a ) )
```

Comment: but it is indeed one that doesn't do slicing etc in the typical sense of the word (+1 for working in the constraints). Not that I understand the motivation, though.

Comment: I second @eickenberg's praise, although `np.sort(a)` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is your array

```
import numpy as np
arr = ((np.arange(24) % 6 + 1)[:, np.newaxis] * np.ones(22)).ravel()
```

Or this

```
arr = ((np.arange(6)[:, np.newaxis] * np.ones(22))[np.newaxis]
        * np.ones([4, 1, 1])).ravel() + 1
```

Now try

```
arr.reshape(-1, 6, 22).transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(6, -1)
```

This is a different view on the array up until the transpose. On the second reshape numpy has to copy.

---

Here is a way to rearrange data coming out of a 4-channel spectrometer with data specification described in the comments:

```
# data vectors stacked (4 * 132)
data = np.random.randn(528, 32768)

# data vectors divided into original 4 blocks
data.reshape(4, 132, 32768)

# data vectors subdivided into 6 * 22 = 132
data.reshape(4, 6, 22, 32768)
```

As you see, dividing the data into the appropriate compartments works with a single (the last) reshape. The rearrangement is done with `transpose` as follows:

```
# the following operation switches dimensions 0 and 1
# yielding a vector of shape (6, 4, 22, 32768)
data.reshape(4, 6, 22, 32768).transpose(1, 0, 2, 3)

# stack all 4 outputs of 22 lines together into blocks of 88 lines
data.reshape(4, 6, 22, 32768).transpose(1, 0, 2, 3).reshape(6, 88, 32768)

# concatenate everything back to get a reordered matrix
data.reshape(4, 6, 22, 32768).transpose(1, 0, 2, 3).reshape(6 * 88, 32768)
```

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. The trick I ended up using (employing reshape and argsort) has been for some reason deleted from this thread.

Comment: note that this will likely only work on those exact data. What exactly is the application?

Comment: its actually the output of a 4-channel spectrometer with 32k spectral windows. The number rows can always change based on the number of scans done. I have to interleave the data to make sure that I do the right math on the right channels. Any suggestions on the above mentioned problem? I.e. a generic version of the technique replacing integers 1-6 with random/variable values? No need of sorting in the current case.

Comment: any suggestion on this?

Comment: I must admit that I don't really understand the description. I have no way of visualizing the shape of these real data. If you update your question with a description of this, that would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about the confusing statements :) Let me try and elaborate a little better.

Comment: Four channels that come out of 32K spectrometer and each channel produces data array of dimensions (137,32768). If I stack them all vertically, I get an array of dimension (528,32768). Now, in this array, rows 0-137 are from channel1, 138-275 from channel2 and so on. Now, the spectral data processor that comes after, doesn't want to see the rows of data in the current order. It wants say n-rows from each channel and group them together. And that operation needs to happen all across the (528,32768) array.....(contd).

Comment: Now lets say n-rows = 22, the first 22 rows from each channel in the array should be picked up and grouped together; then, the "@2nd pile of 22 rows should be picked from each channel and grouped together and so on...I'm calling that process as interleaving of groups of rows.... Hoping that the description sounds better now.

Comment: OK, I'll update my answer. You'll have to check if I understood correctly. As it happens, 137 is not divisible by 22. What should be done with the remaining 5 channels (6 * 22 + 5 = 137)? If this is irrelevant, then I have misunderstood your description.

Comment: Oh my mistake....it should be 132 in this example not 137. So 6 * 22 = 132; 132 * 4 = 528

Comment: Answer updated. If I understand correctly, your output should be in the last line, the rest is pedagogical. I am turning everything back into a matrix. Maybe it should be ravelled into one long vector? If so, just apply `.ravel()` to the result.